# PagedList invalidating DataSource

Tags: android, pagedlist

Here's PageList refresh method:

```
public void refresh() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        ItemViewModel itemViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(MainActivity.this)
                .get(ItemViewModel.class);
        final ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(MainActivity.this);

        itemViewModel.itemPagedList.observe(MainActivity.this,
                new Observer<PagedList<Item>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<Item> items) {

                        adapter.submitList(items);

                    }
                });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

But it doesn't provide new version of data, so I need to use `invalidate()` to `ItemDataSource`. How can I do that?

Here's `ItemDataSource`:

```
public class ItemDataSource extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, Item> {
    @Override
    public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull final LoadInitialCallback<Integer, Item> callback) {

        loadData(Util.getMinAge, Util.getMaxAge);
    }
    // and so on in loadBefore and loadAfter methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue by adding getter for DataSource:

```
public static ItemDataSource getItemDataSource() {
        return itemDataSource;
    }

    private static ItemDataSource itemDataSource;

    @Override
    public DataSource<Integer, Item> create() {
        itemDataSource = new ItemDataSource();

        itemLiveDataSource.postValue(itemDataSource);

        return itemDataSource;
    }
```

Then I added this line before refreshing:

```
        ItemDataSourceFactory.getItemDataSource().invalidate();
```

This helped me to get new version of data for PagedList.

Comment: You probably don't need it to be static tbh